# jQuery results list with multiple filters

Tags: jquery, filtering

I am trying to put together a filter on a list (generated from a database), but I'm getting the feeling I'm going down a complicated path. Or rather, I'm stuck and have no idea how to go from here. What I have so far is shown below.

**The filter section:**

```
<div id="searchfilter">
  <form id="filterform" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p>Search Filters</p>
    <p>By Area of Expertise</p>
      <ul id="funtion">
        <li>
          <label>
            <span>All areas of expertise</span>
            <input class="resetfilter" type="checkbox" name="cbxFunction" id="cbxFunction_0" value="all" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <span>Administration</span>
            <input class="filter" type="checkbox" name="cbxFunction" id="cbxFunction_1" value="administration" />
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <span>Animal Health</span>
            <input class="filter" type="checkbox" name="cbxFunction" id="cbxFunction_2" value="animal-health" />
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <span>Creative</span>
            <input class="filter" type="checkbox" name="cbxFunction" id="cbxFunction_3" value="creative" />
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <span>Marketing</span>
            <input class="filter" type="checkbox" name="cbxFunction" id="cbxFunction_3" value="marketing" />
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <span>Information Technology</span>
            <input class="filter" type="checkbox" name="cbxFunction" id="cbxFunction_3" value="information-technology" />
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <span>Research &amp; Development</span>
            <input class="filter" type="checkbox" name="cbxFunction" id="cbxFunction_3" value="research-and-development" />
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <p>By Location</p>

      <ul id="country">
        <li>
          <label>
            <span>All countries</span>
            <input class="resetfilter" type="checkbox" name="cbxLocation" id="cbxLocation_0" value="all" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <span>Malaysia</span>
            <input class="filter" type="checkbox" name="cbxLocation" id="cbxLocation_1" value="malaysia" />
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <span>The Netherlands</span>
            <input class="filter" type="checkbox" name="cbxLocation" id="cbxLocation_1" value="the-netherlands" />
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <span>United Kingdom</span>
            <input class="filter" type="checkbox" name="cbxLocation" id="cbxLocation_2" value="united-kingdom" />
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**The results section:**

```
  <div>
    <h3>Current Vacancies</h3>
    <ul class="pagelink">
      <li class="job-listing function country administration the-netherlands">
        Assistant Regulatory Affairs Manager<br />
        Administration, The Netherlands
      </li>
      <li class="job-listing function country animal-health united-kingdom">
        Clinical Research Associate<br />
        Animal Health, United Kingdom
      </li>
      <li class="job-listing function country creative malaysia">
        Copywriter<br />
        Creative, Malaysia
      </li>
      <li class="job-listing function country administration malaysia">
        Corporate Communications Manager<br />
        Administration, Malaysia
      </li>
      <li class="job-listing function country marketing the-netherlands">
        Customer Service Associate<br />
        Marketing, The Netherlands
      </li>
      <li class="job-listing function country research-and-development the-netherlands">
        Emerging Technology Specialist<br />
        Research &amp; Development, The Netherlands
      </li>
      <li class="job-listing function country information-technology united-kingdom">
        Legal Counsel - Intellectual Property (IP)<br />
        Information Technology, United Kingdom
      </li>
      <li class="job-listing function country information-technology the-netherlands">
        Legal Counsel – Drafting Intelectual Property (IP) Related Agreements<br />
        Information Technology, The Netherlands
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.filter').change(function() {
    $filter = $(this).val();
    $filtertype = $(this).parents('ul').attr('id');
    $(this).parents('ul').find('input.resetfilter:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
    $(this).parents('ul').find('input.resetfilter:checkbox').removeAttr("disabled");

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.pagelink').find('li.'+$filter).show();
    }
    else
    {
            $('.pagelink').find('li.'+$filter).hide();
    }
});

$('.resetfilter').change(function() {
    $filtertype = $(this).parents('ul').attr('id');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.pagelink').find('li.'+$filtertype).show();
            $(this).parents('ul').find('input.filter:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
            $(this).parents('ul').find('input.resetfilter:checkbox').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

What I would like to accomplish here is to be able to select any value from either one of the two filter lists and show the results accordingly. Where I am particularly stuck is the part where if I select the "All" value of one of the two filter lists, I'm not sure how to get the right results to show while still keeping the active filters of 'the other list' into consideration.

I'm guessing I may have to look at arrays instead, but I have no idea how to go about it in that case.

Any pointers in the right direction are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.filter').change(function() {

  // Get all checked filters...
  var $allCheckedFilters = $('input.filter:checked');
  var checkedValues = [];

  // Iterate and build array containing all checked values...
  $allCheckedFilters.each(function(index, element){
    checkedValues.push($(this).val());
  })

  // Build string to use as selector...
  var classNameStr = checkedValues.join('.');    

  // Hide all listings...
  $('.job-listing').hide();

  // Get items with all classnames and show them...
  $('li.' + classNameStr).show();

});

$('.resetfilter').change(function() {
    // Get the parent UL...
    var $parentUl = $(this).parents('ul');

    // Get the checkboxes from the section the checkbox we just checked was in...
    var $thisSectionCheckboxes = $parentUl.find('input.filter');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      // Check all checkboxes in the current section...
      $thisSectionCheckboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
    }else{
      // User unchecked the All checkbox. So uncheck all checkboxes in this section
      $thisSectionCheckboxes.removeAttr('checked');
    }

    // Let the change handler we added above handle the show and hide of the relevant sections...
    $thisSectionCheckboxes.first().trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much for you quick and useful reply! I'm still trying to dissect what you did, but despite my limited grasp of jQuery, I'm starting to make sense of it. One question though, it looks like your solution treats all the checkboxes as AND rather than OR? For instance, when I select "Administration" and "The Netherlands" I correctly get 1 result. However, when I also select "Malaysia", I should get 2 results, but instead I'm getting 0 results. Any suggestion on where I should change that?

Comment: Yes, I'm currently treating them as AND. Try this for OR: http://jsfiddle.net/JhU9G/. However if we're doing OR, taking your example, choosing "Administration" and "The Netherlands" would return 5 results because you're saying "Administration" OR "The Netherlands".

Comment: Hi Lee, apologies for the late follow-up. So, your answer is quite a step in the direction I'm looking for, thanks! However I've been trying to fiddle your script to get the complete result I'm after, but am stuck once more. Right now, the results are like this: COUNTRIES(..OR..OR..OR) OR LOCATIONS(..OR..OR..). What I'm trying to accomplish is COUNTRIES(..OR..OR..) AND LOCATIONS(..OR..OR..).